# std::string gives errors in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, stdvector

I'm studying SimConnect/WASM to be able to connect my cockpit hardware with MSFS2020. I am using [MobiFlight](https://www.mobiflight.com/en/index.html) as a source of information, because their tool is open source. I'm currently looking in their WASM module for which the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/MobiFlight/MobiFlight-WASM-Module).

I can open the solution in VS2019 (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 - Version 16.11.7 VisualStudio.16.Release/16.11.7+31911.196). I only had to remove the Command Line in the Post-Build Event of the project to be able to build it with success.

At least, the final line in my Output window says: "========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========".

Still I'm getting several "red curly error marks" in the source file "module.cpp" (only cpp file in this build). Several seem related to std::string. Below is a screenshot of such error, which seems to be related to a constructor (but goes way over my knowledge to understand):

[image]

If I hover over the word "std" and use "Peek Definition", then I land somewhere in "vector", which is indeed used in this code.

I can't tell if the code is working (at least not yet). But it generates the output file "StandaloneModule.wasm", so I guess all is ok. But if errors are generated, how can the build be successful?

I hope somebody can shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Intellisense can sometimes get confused, if the code compiles correctly then just ignore the error (if your visual studio is fully up to date then you could submit a bug report with a [mre] to Microsoft)

Comment: ..also, using `char const*` instead of `char*` might help.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have now updated VS2019 to version 16.11.8, but still see the same errors. But as you suggested, I will ignore them. In the meantime, I can also confirm that my own built "StandaloneModule.wasm" is working, so there seems indeed no issue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have tried this, but with no luck. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: The "error" presented is generated by the IDE not by the compiler.  It is independent of the compiler, and may not produce the same results. Treat it as a warning that the code may not compile rather than an error.  However it is not immediately obvious why you are getting this warning, but it is an answer to _"But if errors are generated, how can the build be successful?"_

Comment: The fact that the messages have `std::__2` as the namespace rather than `std` makes me wonder whether Intellisense in the IDE thinks you're using the version of C++ (and its library) that's different than what the actual build does.